# Flutter Slider Not Moving or Updating

Tags: flutter

I'm learning Flutter (and coding in general) and I can't seem to find the issue with my latest project. When I run in simulator the slider forms just fine, click the thumb and the label shows, but the thumb won't move on the track at all, and thus never calls the onChanged event.

```
import 'resources.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class ItemDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;

  ItemDetail({Key key, @required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemDetailState createState() => new _ItemDetailState(item: item);
}

class _ItemDetailState extends State<ItemDetail> {
  Item item;

  _ItemDetailState({Key key, @required this.item});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double margin = ((item.listPrice - item.stdUnitCost)/item.listPrice)*100;
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text('Item Detail'),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0)),
          new Text(item.itemCode),
          new Text(item.itemDescription),
          new Text(item.itemExtendedDescription),
          new Divider(height: 40.0,),
          new Text('List Price: \$${item.listPrice}'),
          new Text('Cost: \$${item.stdUnitCost}'),
          item.itemType=='N'
              ? new Text('Non-Stock (${item.itemType})')
              : new Text('Stock Item (${item.itemType})'),
          new Text('Available: ${item.stockAvailable}'),
          new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0)),
          new Slider(
            value: margin,
            divisions: 20,
            min: 0.0,
            max: 100.0,
            label: margin.round().toString(),
            onChanged: (double value) {
              setState(() {
                margin = value;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Problem:** In the above example, `margin` is not a **state variable**. It is a local variable inside a `build` method.

**Fix:** Move this as an **instance** variable.

**Reason:** Widgets will get **rebuild** only when there is a change in **its state**.

**Code:**

```
class _ItemDetailState extends State<ItemDetail> {
  Item item;
  var margin;

  _ItemDetailState({Key key, @required this.item}) {
    this.margin = ((item.listPrice - item.stdUnitCost)/item.listPrice)*100;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //same as now
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

For others coming here, I had a slightly different reason that the slider wasn't updating. I had the `value` set to a constant. Make sure that value is a variable.

This:

```
Slider(
  value: _myValue,
  ...
  onChanged: (newValue) => {
    setState(() => _myValue = newValue)
  },
),
```

Not this:

```
Slider(
  value: 0, //                     <-- problem
  ...
  onChanged: (newValue) => {
    setState(() => _myValue = newValue)
  },
),
```

Answer (score 15):

I got this issue when I put the variable inside the build function

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

int brightness = 85;

return Scaffold(
...
```

Moved the variable outside the function and got it solved

```
int brightness = 85;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
...
```

because each time when state is changed, this build method is called and sets the variable back to the assigned value

Comment: the answer didnt help me, but the answering mode is dope

Answer (score 6):

This might help!   (**I USED STATEFULBUILDER TO UPDATE THE VALUE**)

```
               double _value = 20;

               StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (context, state) => Center(
                    child: CupertinoSlider(
                      value: _value,
                      min: 0.0,
                      max: 100.0,
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        state(() {
                          _value = val;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: This is the solution incase you are using slider in bottom dialog

Comment: Not work with alert dialog  unable to update value on text filed from onChange.

Answer (score 1):

I think the variable margin does not have scope from where the UI is building. When you debug, you can see changes in variable but  it is not rendering. I tried it in following way and able to update the UI value.

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

     double margin=0;

     Widget getSlider(BuildContext context)
      {

        return Slider(
      value:margin.toDouble(),
      onChanged: (newRating){

        setState(() {
          margin = newRating;
        });

      },
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      divisions: 5,
    );
   } // getslider method closed
     // @0verride Widget build method
    // under children widgets , simply call the getSlider method to place the slider
 } //class
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue when giving the `Slider(value: tasksDetails.taskImportance.toDouble(), etc)`

I used `Slider((_currentImportance ?? tasksDetails.taskImportance).toDouble(), etc)`

and could then move the slider. I have no idea why this now works. Can only guess something to do with Denish's reason above 'Reason: Widgets will get rebuild only when there is a change in its state'. The selected slider value was in both cases was save correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My first problem was answered by Dinesh. Then the slider wasn't smooth. I was only able to tap to get it to move. I am on iOS, so I changed the `Slider` widget to `Slider.adaptive`.
This changes the slider to a `CupertinoSlider`.

Copy and paste class for your testing convenience:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  double _currentSliderValue = 20;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider.adaptive(
      value: _currentSliderValue,
      max: 100,
      divisions: 5,
      label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
      onChanged: (double value) {
        setState(() {
          _currentSliderValue = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the build tree was in a FutureBuilder, and the slider updates would get stuck at the async call. Moving the sliders to a widget under the FutureBuilder widget fixed the problem.