# ListView.builder Not Building Items (nothing is displayed)

Tags: dart, flutter

When I don't use the `ListView.builder` constructor in Flutter, the individual item is shown as expected from the JSON API:

On the other hand, when I use `ListView.builder`, nothing shows up.

Here's the code:

```
 import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart'as http;

import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
Map responsee={};
bool _loading = false;




class tag extends StatefulWidget{

  Map data={};
  tag(this.data);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return tagstate(data);
  }

}

class tagstate extends State<tag>{
  List influ=[{"username":"tarun"}];

  Map data={};
  tagstate(this.data);

  Future<Null> load()async {

    responsee = await getJson1(data["tag"]);
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
      influ=responsee["influencers"];
      new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 5), _login);


    });
    print('length: ${influ}');

  }
  Future _login() async{
    setState((){
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    load();
    super.initState();

  }




  @override
   build(BuildContext context) {

    var bodyProgress = new Container(
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[

          new Container(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white70,
            ),
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue[200],
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
              ),
              width: 300.0,
              height: 200.0,
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Center(
                    child: new SizedBox(
                      height: 50.0,
                      width: 50.0,
                      child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
                        value: null,
                        strokeWidth: 7.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                    child: new Center(
                      child: new Text(
                        "loading.. wait...",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text("Stats",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
      ),
      body:  _loading ? bodyProgress : new Column(children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(child: ListView.builder(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.5),itemCount: influ.length,itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int pos){
          new ListTile(
            title: Text(influ[pos]["username"],style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.9),),


            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
              child: Image.network("${influ[pos]["photo"]}"),

            ),

          );
        }),)],),


    );

  }
}
Future<Map> getJson1(String data) async{
  String apiUrl="https://api.ritekit.com/v1/influencers/hashtag/$data?client_id=a59c9bebeb5253f830e09bd9edd102033c8fe014b976";
  http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
  return json.decode(response.body);

}
```

No matter how much I try, the error still persists.

The Scaffold loads, but the `ListView.builder` doesn't.

When I don't use the `ListView.builder`, the individual item is shown as expected from the JSON API.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone...
I actually forgot to return the Listtile in the Itembuiler Function..

Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<Null> load()async {
  responsee = await getJson1(data["tag"]);
  influ=responsee["influencers"];
}
```

should be

```
Future<Null> load()async {
  responsee = await getJson1(data["tag"]);
  setState(() => influ=responsee["influencers"]);
}
```

`await getJson1(data["tag"]);` is async and needs to notify Flutter to rebuild when the response arrives.

Comment: I've Changed It by Adding SetState as you've mentioned, but nothing seems to show up still

Comment: What is the output if you add `print('length: ${influ.length}');` as last line to `load()`?

Comment: And the Irony is...If you run the Same code without Listbuilder..It works Magically for single element..

Comment: flutter: length: 10

Answer (score 0):

Move `List influ = []` into tagState class and use setState as above answer. Everything should work now.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007907/flutter-slider-not-moving-or-updating/52008490#52008490). `influ` was global variable initially because of which even `setState` will not work. If we want our `Stateful widget` to **react** based on some value, it should be its `instance` variable, not **local** variable and not **global** variable.

Comment: Tried..but no luck here as well

Comment: Are u getting data from backend? Can u put some print and show the value of `influ` after await

Comment: Yes, the backend works abosolutely fine. As far As I Have noticed, The Values get printed after the Scaffold shows up. Dont know why set state isnt working

Comment: I updated my answer with **why we have to move influ inside tagState**

Answer (score 0):

Because load() is async, it's not sure what "tagstate.build()" does. My suggestion is to do the loading in the parent widget, then when the loading is done, pass influ to the tag widget. E.g.

```
onPress(() {
  final influ = (await getJson1(data["tag"]))['influencers'];
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    (new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return tag(influ: influe);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Tried it.. But The error still persists. I edited the code now as I also now tried it with the loader.The loader works fine, but the builder still dos'ent. I guess the's something to do with state Management