# Slider(created in custom class) not moving or updating

Tags: flutter, slider

I have just started out android app development using flutter and I am learning along the way.

**Details about current project:** 
I am creating a dice simulator, in which user can tap on the drawn dice to roll the dice. I have added vibration effect, toast also. Now I want to let user modify the size of the dice using a slider.

I have found a [slider class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) in documentation.
I have also consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007907/flutter-slider-not-moving-or-updating) thread in stackoverflow.Still, I can't grasp the concept completely. I would appreciate any help.

**Problem:**

Said slider does render how it is supposed to be but I can't seem to be able to drag it.

### main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:do_dice/dice2D.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

void showToastText(int a) {
  Fluttertoast
      .cancel(); //to clear all scheduled toast call ; this is to make the toast cal seem instant responsive.
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: '$a',
    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
    textColor: Colors.yellow,
    fontSize: 14.0,
  );
}

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.0), //status bar is transparent
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ROLL THE DICE',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'ROLL THE DICE'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Dice2D dice1 = new Dice2D(
    size: 300.0,
    borderWidth: 5.0,
    displayInt: 2,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
            child: Text(
          widget.title,
        )),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SliderDiceSize(
            minValue: 100.0,
            maxValue: 300.0,
            title: "Set the size of dice:",
            dice: dice1,
            titleColor: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          SliderBorderWidth(titleColor: Colors.yellow,title: "Set the border width of dice:",dice: dice1,minValue: 1.0,maxValue: 10.0,),
          Expanded(child: Center(child: dice1)),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //function to display the number on dice as a toast
          showToastText(dice1.getDisplay());
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
        tooltip: "Show the number.",
        child: Icon(Icons.message),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

### dice2D.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';

void vibrateDiceRolling() {
  Vibration.cancel();
  Vibration.vibrate(duration: 50); //default is 500 ms
}

void showToastRolling() {
  Fluttertoast
      .cancel(); //to clear all scheduled toast call ; this is to make the toast call seem instant responsive.
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: "Roger that!",
    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
    textColor: Colors.white70,
    fontSize: 14.0,
  );
}

class paintDice2D extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  @required
  final int display;
  @required
  final double borderWidth;
  @required
  final Color diceColor;
  @required
  final double diceSize;

  paintDice2D(
      {Key key, this.diceSize, this.display, this.borderWidth, this.diceColor})
      : super(key: key);

  Widget drawEmptyBox() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(),
    );
  }

  Widget drawCircleDot() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: diceColor),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double divSize = (diceSize - 2 * borderWidth) / 3;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
        border: Border.all(
            color: diceColor, width: borderWidth, style: BorderStyle.solid),
      ),
      height: diceSize,
      width: diceSize,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: (display == 3 ||
                            display == 4 ||
                            display == 5 ||
                            display == 6) ==
                        true
                    ? drawCircleDot()
                    : drawEmptyBox(), // condition == true ?  {code for true } : {code for false}
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child:
                    (display == 6) == true ? drawCircleDot() : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: (display == 2 ||
                            display == 4 ||
                            display == 5 ||
                            display == 6) ==
                        true
                    ? drawCircleDot()
                    : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: (display == 1 || display == 3 || display == 5) == true
                    ? drawCircleDot()
                    : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: (display == 2 ||
                            display == 4 ||
                            display == 5 ||
                            display == 6) ==
                        true
                    ? drawCircleDot()
                    : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child:
                    (display == 6) == true ? drawCircleDot() : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: (display == 3 ||
                            display == 4 ||
                            display == 5 ||
                            display == 6) ==
                        true
                    ? drawCircleDot()
                    : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dice2D extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  @required
  double size;
  @required
  double borderWidth;
  @required
  int displayInt;

  Dice2D({
    Key key,
    this.size,
    this.borderWidth,
    this.displayInt,
  }) : super(key: key);

  int getDisplay() {
    return this.displayInt;
  }

  Dice2DState createState() {
    return new Dice2DState();
  }
}

class Dice2DState extends State<Dice2D> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int nextDisplay = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
        void rollDice() {
            setState(() {
                widget.displayInt = nextDisplay;
                nextDisplay = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                showToastRolling();
                vibrateDiceRolling();
            });
        }

        return FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
                rollDice();
            },
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: paintDice2D(
                display: widget.displayInt,
                borderWidth: widget.borderWidth,
                diceSize: widget.size,
                diceColor: Colors.yellow,
            ),
        );
    }
  }


class SliderDiceSize extends StatefulWidget {
  @required final String title;
  @required Dice2D dice;
  @required final double minValue;
  @required final double maxValue;
  @required final Color titleColor;

  SliderDiceSize({Key key, this.title,  this.dice, this.titleColor, this.maxValue, this.minValue}):super(key:key);

  @override
  SliderDiceSizeState createState() {
    return new SliderDiceSizeState();
  }
}

class SliderDiceSizeState extends State<SliderDiceSize> {

  void setDiceSize(double a) {
    setState(() {
      int diceint = widget.dice.getDisplay(); //**
      widget.dice.displayInt = diceint; //**
      widget.dice.size = a; //**
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: new Text(
            widget.title,
            style: TextStyle(color: widget.titleColor, fontSize: 16.0),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: new Slider(
            value: widget.dice.size, //**
            onChanged: (double value) => setDiceSize(value), //**
            max: widget.maxValue,
            min: widget.minValue,
            activeColor: Colors.grey,
            inactiveColor: Colors.white12,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SliderBorderWidth extends StatefulWidget {
  @required
  final String title;
  @required
  Dice2D dice;
  @required final double minValue;
  @required final double maxValue;
  @required final Color titleColor;

  SliderBorderWidth(
      {Key key,
      this.dice,
      this.title,
      this.minValue,
      this.maxValue,
      this.titleColor});

  @override
  SliderBorderWidthState createState() {
    return new SliderBorderWidthState();
  }
}

class SliderBorderWidthState extends State<SliderBorderWidth> {
    void setBorderWidth(double a) {
    setState(() {
        int diceint = widget.dice.getDisplay();  //**
        widget.dice.borderWidth = a;  //**
    });}

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: new Text(
          widget.title,
            style: TextStyle(color: widget.titleColor, fontSize: 16.0),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: new Slider(
            value: widget.dice.borderWidth,  //**
            onChanged: (double value) => setBorderWidth(value),  //**
            max: widget.maxValue,
            min: widget.minValue,
            activeColor: Colors.grey,
            inactiveColor: Colors.white12,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Below is new full code using callback function. I have marked updated lines of code using ~~ .
Earlier problem of slider not being able to drag has popped up again. My suspicion of lines which are causing problems are marked by comment in the code.

### main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
import 'package:do_dice/dice2D.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

void showToastText(int a) {
  Fluttertoast
      .cancel(); //to clear all scheduled toast call ; this is to make the toast cal seem instant responsive.
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: '$a',
    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
    textColor: Colors.yellow,
    fontSize: 14.0,
  );
}

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.0), //status bar is transparent
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ROLL THE DICE',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'ROLL THE DICE'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Dice2D dice1 = new Dice2D(
    size: 300.0,
    borderWidth: 5.0,
    displayInt: 2,
  );

//~~ added this function to serve as callback
updateDiceSize(Dice2D dice,double size){
    setState((){  
        dice.size = size;
    });
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
            child: Text(
          widget.title,
        )),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SliderDiceSize(updateDiceSizeCallback: updateDiceSize(dice1,dice1.size),  //~~passing the callback
            minValue: 100.0,
            maxValue: 300.0,
            title: "Set the size of dice:",
            dice: dice1,
            titleColor: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          Expanded(child: Center(child: dice1)),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //function to display the number on dice as a toast
          showToastText(dice1.getDisplay());
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
        tooltip: "Show the number.",
        child: Icon(Icons.message),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Dice2D.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:vibration/vibration.dart';

void vibrateDiceRolling() {
  Vibration.cancel();
  Vibration.vibrate(duration: 50); //default is 500 ms
}

void showToastRolling() {
  Fluttertoast
      .cancel(); //to clear all scheduled toast call ; this is to make the toast call seem instant responsive.
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: "Roger that!",
    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
    textColor: Colors.white70,
    fontSize: 14.0,
  );
}

class PaintDice2D extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  @required
  final int display;
  @required
  final double borderWidth;
  @required
  final Color diceColor;
  @required
  final double diceSize;

  PaintDice2D(
      {Key key, this.diceSize, this.display, this.borderWidth, this.diceColor})
      : super(key: key);

  Widget drawEmptyBox() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(),
    );
  }

  Widget drawCircleDot() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: diceColor),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double divSize = (diceSize - 2 * borderWidth) / 3;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
        border: Border.all(
            color: diceColor, width: borderWidth, style: BorderStyle.solid),
      ),
      height: diceSize,
      width: diceSize,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: (display == 3 ||
                            display == 4 ||
                            display == 5 ||
                            display == 6) ==
                        true
                    ? drawCircleDot()
                    : drawEmptyBox(), // condition == true ?  {code for true } : {code for false}
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child:
                    (display == 6) == true ? drawCircleDot() : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: (display == 2 ||
                            display == 4 ||
                            display == 5 ||
                            display == 6) ==
                        true
                    ? drawCircleDot()
                    : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: (display == 1 || display == 3 || display == 5) == true
                    ? drawCircleDot()
                    : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: (display == 2 ||
                            display == 4 ||
                            display == 5 ||
                            display == 6) ==
                        true
                    ? drawCircleDot()
                    : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child:
                    (display == 6) == true ? drawCircleDot() : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
              Container(
                width: divSize,
                height: divSize,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(divSize / 5),
                child: (display == 3 ||
                            display == 4 ||
                            display == 5 ||
                            display == 6) ==
                        true
                    ? drawCircleDot()
                    : drawEmptyBox(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dice2D extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  @required
  double size;
  @required
  double borderWidth;
  @required
  int displayInt;

  Dice2D({
    Key key,
    this.size,
    this.borderWidth,
    this.displayInt,
  }) : super(key: key);

  int getDisplay() {
    return this.displayInt;
  }

  Dice2DState createState() {
    return new Dice2DState();
  }
}

class Dice2DState extends State<Dice2D> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int nextDisplay = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
        void rollDice() {
            setState(() {
                widget.displayInt = nextDisplay;
                nextDisplay = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                showToastRolling();
                vibrateDiceRolling();
            });
        }

        return FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
                rollDice();
            },
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: PaintDice2D(
                display: widget.displayInt,
                borderWidth: widget.borderWidth,
                diceSize: widget.size,
                diceColor: Colors.yellow,
            ),
        );
    }
  }


class SliderDiceSize extends StatefulWidget {
  @required final String title;
  @required Dice2D dice;
  @required final double minValue;
  @required final double maxValue;
  @required final Color titleColor;
  @required Function updateDiceSizeCallback;  //~~
  SliderDiceSize({Key key, this.title,  this.dice, this.titleColor, this.maxValue, this.minValue,this.updateDiceSizeCallback}):super(key:key);  //~~

  @override
  SliderDiceSizeState createState() {
    return new SliderDiceSizeState();
  }
}

class SliderDiceSizeState extends State<SliderDiceSize> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: new Text(
            widget.title,
            style: TextStyle(color: widget.titleColor, fontSize: 16.0),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: new Slider(
            value: widget.dice.size,
            onChanged: (double value) => widget.updateDiceSizeCallback, //~~ I believe something needs to change here for slider to be able to drag.
            max: widget.maxValue,
            min: widget.minValue,
            activeColor: Colors.grey,
            inactiveColor: Colors.white12,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

since, this is my first question here, I apologize for messed up code and variable names.

Comment: Could you share the complete code/repo? Maybe I can check it later.

Comment: I included the full code. Btw, I messed around a little in SliderDiceSizeState class (marked by **) and somehow got the slider to be able to drag. but the new problem has arise. When slider is dragged, it isn't updating the state of Dice2D object but when tapped on the dice itself (a function rolldice() in Dice2DState) it sets it's new size according to the values set by sliders. Should I edit the question itself?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer. Maybe that will make things more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving, and using, the properties inside the widget instead of the state class.
As I understand the `widget` of the `StatefulWidget` is just like a `StatelessWidget`. The actual `state` should be in the `State<>` class that the `StatefulWidget` creates.

Try adding the property for the dice (`Dice2D`) to the actual state class.

[edit]

Okay so I've taken a closer look at your code and I think you are not updating the right `State`.
Your sliders are only updating their own `State` (which is what `setState()` does). But they should be updating their parents `State` (`_MyHomePageState`) because that will trigger the `MyHomePageWidget` to rebuild with the new `State`.
Your `Die` is rebuilding properly when clicking on it because this triggers the `Dice2DState` to update it's own state which DOES trigger a rebuild of the Dice2D Widget.

So that's the problem. Now how to solve this. You need a way to trigger a `setState()` on the `_MyHomePageState`. There are different ways to do this. But because you are just trying out some stuff I suggest you use callbacks.

In your `_MyHomePageState` you add the following function:

```
// Could also be separate functions for each property
updateDice({double size, double borderWidth, int displayInt}) {
    setState(() {
     if(size != null) dice1.size = size;
     if(borderWidth != null) dice1.borderWidth = borderWidth;
     if(displayInt != null) dice1.displayInt = displayInt; 
    });
  }
```

This will be used to update the `Dice`.

Your sliders will have to make use off this so pass this function as a callback in the constructor of the sliders:
`SliderBorderWidth(updateDice ... rest of your params ...)`

and store it in your slider widget:
`Function updateDiceCallback`

[more about passing functions here](https://code-maven.com/slides/dart-programming/passing-functions-as-parameters)

Now your sliders can use this callback to update the state of your dice.
Because your dice's state is now being managed higher up the hierarchy your Dice Widget should be a `StatelessWidget` because it get's redrawn anyway and is just a visual representation.
You should also pass the `UpdateDice`-callback to it so you can wire it up to the `OnPressed` event or something and make it update the number.

I hope this make any sense to you. I was trying to fix your code but I think you need to understand the way state works better. I will create an example for you and add it.

[sample]

Try this, maybe it will help you understand. Just past it in the main.dart of a new project.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ROLL THE DICE',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'ROLL THE DICE'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Dice2D dice1 = new Dice2D(
    size: 150.0,
    displayInt: 2,
  );

  updateDice({double size, int displayInt}) {
    setState(() {
     if(size != null) dice1.size = size;
     if(displayInt != null) dice1.displayInt = displayInt; 
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
            child: Text(
          widget.title,
        )),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Slider(
            value: dice1.size,
            min: 100.0,
            max: 200.0,
            onChanged: (value){
            updateDice(size: value);
          },),
          DiceWidget(dice1.size, dice1.displayInt, updateDice),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DiceWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final int _number;
  final double _size;
  final Function _onPressed;

  DiceWidget(this._size, this._number, this._onPressed);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: (){
        _onPressed(displayInt: Random().nextInt(5)+1);
      },
      child: Text("$_number", style: TextStyle(fontSize: _size),)),);
  }
}

class Dice2D {
  var size;
  var displayInt;

  Dice2D({this.size,this.displayInt});
}
```

Comment: May I recommend to elaborate a little on the "How?" and the "Why?".

Comment: It's more of a suggestion but yeah, I will elaborate.

Comment: Be careful, if you give the impression that it is more of a suggestion than an assertive answer, then you might catch some flags "should be a comment".

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting. But then how do I create object of Dice2D class in main.dart?

Comment: Yep, it works! I understood the concept of updating the State of parent widget to trigger change of State in children widget. But this leads me to believe that we can't trigger state of classA from completely unrelated sibling classB. How much of this assumption is true? and If there is a way to achieve this I would like to implement that rather than crowding the main.dart code. And Thanks for being patience with newbie like me.

Comment: If two siblings should rely on the same state, as in your case the sliders and the dicewidget, the state should be managed by their parent. That's why you use a callback to 'tell' the parent to update its own state, making it rebuild the children with the new properties. The StatefullWidget approach seems to be the easiest way to manage state but it's also getting messy really fast. I suggest you look into the BLoC pattern. This will completely move the state outside your widget tree keeping things clear and neat.

Comment: I am really grateful. I have cleared the issue related to this particular question. onto the next :-P.