# flutter Slider Widget Issue: Thumb Not Moving or onChanged Event Not Triggering

Tags: flutter

I'm facing an issue with a Flutter app I'm developing. The problem is related to the Slider widget. When I run the app in the simulator, the Slider appears correctly, but I'm unable to drag the thumb to change its value. Additionally, the onChanged event is not triggering as expected.

I've looked into my code and suspect that the issue might be related to how I'm using the Slider or the surrounding widgets. I've also tried various solutions, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007907/flutter-slider-not-moving-or-updating)

but the problem persists.

Could someone please review my code and help me identify what might be causing this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

this my code

```
  double cigaretteCount = 0.0;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(""),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: MyContainer(child: Text("Container 1"))),
                Expanded(child: MyContainer(child: Text("Container 2"))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: MyContainer(
                        child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("How many Cigarette do you smoke"),
                    Text(cigaretteCount.toString()),
                    Slider(
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        value: cigaretteCount,
                        onChanged: (double val) {
                          setState(() {
                            cigaretteCount = val;
                          });
                        }),
                  ],
```

this the widgets class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry margin; // Margin değeri için instance variable eklendi.

  MyContainer({required this.child, this.margin = const EdgeInsets.all(12)}); // Default margin değeri verildi.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: margin, // Margin değeri instance variable olarak kullanılıyor.
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class SexWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final sex;
  SexWidget({required this.sex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.person),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Text(sex),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you declared `cigaretteCount` inside the build method. Move it out of it as a direct member of the state class

Comment: Yeah! on changing state it keep getting the initial value again..

Comment: @pixel I think you misunderstand my answer. And also the question you linked because there it also tells the correct answer. You have `double cigaretteCount = 0.0;` in the wrong place. It is inside of the `build` method. It shouldn't be there!. Move it from there, because otherwise it will get set to 0 on every rebuild

Comment: mate chill! it's not my question, and we are on the same page. I'm saying on same thing on every changing state(rebuild) `cigaratteCount` will get reinitiated to 0.0.

Comment: @pixel then what's your question? Because that's the error

Comment: nothing! i was just agreeing with you and trying to give a small explanation.

Comment: I feel like an idiot .. right now

Comment: @pixel all this time I thought you were the one asking the original question. sorry I misunderstood your responses